# ¿Como instalar Laravel 5.5 en Cloud9?

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu, cloud9

## Instalación de Laravel 5.5 en Cloud 9

#### Procedimiento para crear  un espacio de trabajo en Cloud9 con laravel 5.5

### 1.  Crear Workspace en cloud 9

#### 1.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 1.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 1.3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### 2.  Actualizar la versión de php 5 a 7.1

#### 2.1 consultamos la versión actual de php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2.2 Comando para actualizar php

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php –y
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-cli php7.1-dev php7.1-gd php7.1-intl php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-mysql php7.1-opcache php7.1-bcmath php7.1-mbstring php7.1-soap php7.1-xml php7.1-zip -y

sudo mv /etc/apache2/envvars /etc/apache2/envvars.bak
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 -y
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1 -y
sudo cp /etc/apache2/envvars.bak /etc/apache2/envvars
```

### 3. Instalando  phpmyadmin

```
sudo mysql-ctl install
```

(si ya está instalado le damos a no continuar “N” y pasamos al siguiente comando)

```
sudo mysql-ctl start

sudo phpmyadmin-ctl install
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de ejecutar el comando, nos mostrara el enlace para el uso de phpmyadmin el user sin password.
Si desean inician sesión con su usuario en consola y definen un password

```
mysql -u tuUsuario
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### 4.  Instalando  composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

### 5.  Instalar laravel 5.5

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"
```

Cambiar "blog" a nombre deseado

### 6.  Configurando el virtual host

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-cloud9.conf
```

editamos, y dejamos como se muestra a continuacion:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/blog/public
    ServerName https://${C9_HOSTNAME}:443

    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/workspace/blog/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

ServerName https://${C9_HOSTNAME}
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

bueno, solo agregamos la ubicación de la carpeta public de nuestro proyecto.

luego :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

finalmente corremos nuestra aplicación con el botón de Run Project en la parte superior.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a [es.so] un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo, si bien se [puede responder a las preguntas propias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) te recomiendo mantener el formato de pregunta/respuesta. Haz una pregunta en base a [ask] y publica la respuesta en base a [answer]. Gracias por tu aporte!